# Avoiding values which are on database and adding the new one from list

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, rollback

I was trying to use

```
@Transactional(noRollbackFor = {SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException.class, ConstraintViolationException.class, DataIntegrityViolationException.class})
```

in my **serviceImpl class**

and following for checking exception:-

```
try{
dao.saveAll(list)
}catch (Throwable ignore){
  ...
}
```

but it is not working, can anyone suggest me how to do that, only add non existing data and avoid the rest.

Comment: A transaction is all or nothing, how can you commit 10 out 20 rows without doing a full rollback? If you want that you should start a transaction for each item in your list and do an individual insert. Or use JDBC do a batch insert which takes into account existing items.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the noRollbackFor and do this instead:

```
try {
   // flush will execute the SQL statements
   dao.saveAllAndFlush(list)
} catch (SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException | ConstraintViolationException | DataIntegrityViolationException e){
  ...
}
```

Comment: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: Transaction silently rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only

Comment: This is the error I am getting now

Comment: Try to read noRollbackFor. What happens then?

Comment: It's still giving the same error